# Flat file database vs SQLite for fulltext search PHP

Tags: sqlite, flat-file

I want to develop a PHP application. And I don't want to use MySQL for my application. And I will need full-text search feature for my application. I want to know that which database is best for my needs, Flat file or SQLite database for full-text search. Please suggest me some advantages and disadvantages for both databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to ask, sqlite is better.  It works and is fast.

The advantage of using a flat-file over it is that you have no dependencies on sqlite.  The disadvantages of using it is that you don't have any indexes built in, so all queries will be slower.  It will take a lot of effort to develop it and make sure it is bug free.

Comment: does SQLite supports Full-text Search?

Comment: Yes, it does. It's called FTS: http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html. However, flat files in directories can have an index too, when `dir_index` is enabled in Ext3/4.